# Center content of column with colspan and table borders on Android GridLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a table like this one using GridLayout:

[image]

But so far I have only achieved this approach:

[image]

Using this code:

```
               <GridLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:rowCount="3"
                android:columnCount="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/table_border" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/negro"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="4">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Peso de Bala"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2.59"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="40"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Gramos"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Granos"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </GridLayout>
```

The title seems to be centered correctly but the content is not well centered, what do I need to modify on my layout or what do I need to add for achieving this?, and also I don't know if I'm doing my `<shape>` correctly.

My shape code (`drawable/table_border.xml`) is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/negro"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: use android:gravity= center  in the linear layout

Comment: @RohitPadma Doesn't work adding `android:gravity= center`

Comment: Try that in the textview

Comment: @RohitPadma Still not working...

Comment: my bad got confused android:layout_gravity="center" in the textview. this should work

Comment: @RohitPadma Yes, I tried that also, but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are having trouble centering your text is that your view hierarchy doesn't support what you want to do; the cells in your GridLayout are only as wide as their widest child. If you are developing for API 21+ only, you could look into using weights for your cells.

I recommend re-thinking this layout and implementing it with `ConstraintLayout` instead of `GridView`. This will allow your layout to work on all API levels.

You can also achieve the black border by simply having a black background color on your ConstraintLayout's parent and a white background color on your ConstraintLayout itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Velocidad"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="383"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/label2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Salida M/SEG"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/value1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/label2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="1253"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/value1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Muzzle PIE/SEG"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/value2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/label1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="310"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/label2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="91 MTS M/SEG"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/value3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/label4"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="1017"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/value3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="100 YDS PIE/SEG"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/value4"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/label3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: And if I want to have two tables, next to each other 50% of the screen each...?

Comment: In general you would use a parent LinearLayout and give each child width=0dp and weight=1 (as opposed to width=match_parent as in the example).

Comment: Orientation of LinearLayout would be still "vertical"?

Comment: The orientation of the outermost LinearLayout would be horizontal (since you want two tables side-by-side) but the orientation of each inner LinearLayout would be vertical, as in the example.

Comment: One thing that I just noticed, why when compiling I'm getting this error: `Error:(79, 62) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf' with value '@id/label1').` and with all the id references of constraint

Comment: In my example, I gave the numeric views ids like value1, value2, etc and the textual views ids like label1, label2, etc. If you change the ids of the views themselves, you will have to update the ids you use in the constraints to match.

Comment: No, I noticed the problem, it was that some elements were declared after making reference to them so I just added the `+` symbol on it's reference.